# Is Redpitaya 16k sample size a hard limit?

Tags: redpitaya

I notice looking at the documentation that the scope and AFG supports record lengths of up 16k points. Is there anyway this can be increased (I don't remember this number being quoted throughout the development period) and up to 125k points would be very useful for our applications.

Answer (score 1):

16k samples is not a hard limit. Scope & AWG applications use 16k x 16-bit buffers per channel, resulting in 128kB, which accounts only for half of the total Zynq 7010 BRAM memory. There is also a possibility to use a partition of external 512MB DDR3 RAM memory for signal buffering purpose, shared with Linux OS, or simply to allocate the BRAM memory to a single channel+function combination in case your application does not use all 4 of them.